# MySQL Workbench Migration and PostgreSQL ODBC, cannot connect

Tags: postgresql, migration, mysql-workbench, odbc, debian

I am trying to migrate a PostgreSQL database to MySQL using the MySQL Workbench's Migration Wizard tool.

I am on Debian 11 bullseye and installed MySQL Workbench 8.0.25 using Snap.

It works fine, except it cannot connect to my PostgreSQL database.
The error is:

> ```
> Could not connect to Source DBMS. [000] [...
> ```

For the purpose of migrating the database, I installed the ODBC drivers for PostgreSQL using the `odbc-postgresql` package,
and according to `odbcinst -q -d`, the following drivers are available:

- PostgreSQL ANSI
- PostgreSQL Unicode

The error is still the same.

I can connect to the PostgreSQL server using the `sudo -u postgres psql` command.

Any help to help me debug the situation is appreciated!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please specify **step by step** what you did and where the error first occurred.

Comment: Hi @Vérace, here is what I did: 1. Install MySQL Workbench via Snap => connection error 2. Install odbc-postgresql => same connection error.

Comment: Did you follow [these steps](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-postgresql-drivers-linux.html)?

Comment: No, I did not compile from source, as mentioned above, I have installed the odbc-postgresql package which provides the drivers.

Comment: Also, when I try to open the "ODBC Administrator", there is an error the utility cannot be found. So I can't register the driver from there, and I can't find any package for this. odbcadm does not exist on Debian.

Comment: Sorry - can't be of any more help I'm afraid. Maybe you can get something from [this](https://blog.devart.com/installing-and-configuring-odbc-driver-on-linux.html) - not really my area of expertise I'm afraid!

Comment: I was finally able to install the "iODBC Data Source Administrator", the iodbcadm-gtk package is provided by the iodbc package. But MySQL Workbench still can't find it. Also, adding the driver from the Administrator does not help.